# WebRTC and low performance machines

Tags: performance, webrtc

What happens if we run WebRTC on a device with a processor that is too weak to handle the video. Is WebRTC smart enough to drop down to a lower resolution on its own? Or do we have to manually detect this situation and resize the video depending on the device capability?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are methods in place for Firefox and Chrome and they should work for simple applications but if you are going to have numerous things running on the machine, you may want to handle it and cap/control it yourself.

Improvements are in the works for [chrome currently](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=357513&q=webrtc%20cpu&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

For my weaker machines I have had to decrease the video quality(through media constraints in `getUserMedia`) and put a [cap on the bandwidth](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/discuss-webrtc/xawlhG9jKkY/uq46C_xQwbEJ) in Chrome. This has given me the control over CPU utilization I need where the in browser solution has not.

Firefox does not support bandwidth caps yet(SDP or MediaConstraints), so you will have to rely on media constraints only.